# trying to get simple javascript gallery with next and previous buttons to loop back to the beginning

Tags: javascript, loops, image-gallery

im fairly new to javascript, but im basically trying to make a next/previous click through gallery. I've managed to find tutorials and bits to get images to click through. however i cant seem to work out how to return to the beginning of the series after the 4th(final) image.

this is what i have so far-

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 var photos=new Array()
 var which=0
 photos[0]='images/image1.jpg'
 photos[1]='images/image2.jpg'
 photos[2]='images/image3.jpg'
 photos[3]='images/image4.jpg'

 function backward(){
    if (which > 0){
        which=which-1
        document.images.photoslider.src=photos[which]
    }
 }

 function forward(){
     if (which<photos.length-1){
        which=which+1
        document.images.photoslider.src=photos[which]
     }
 }

 </script>

 <form>
     <input type="button" value="&lt;&lt;Back" onClick="backward()"> 
     <input type="button" value="Next&gt;&gt;" onClick="forward()">
 </form>
```

essentially I want the buttons to create a continuous loop through the 4 images. I know there is going to be a simple solution I just cant see it. Any help would be great! 
thank you in advance!

Comment: Some tips: use `[]` instead of `new Array()`, as it's faster and takes less space, and put semicolons where they are needed, because even though JavaScript automatically inserts them, sometimes it will insert them in unexpected places and cause unexpected errors.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
function backward() {
    if (which <= 0) {
        which = photos.length - 1;
    } else {
        which--;
    }
    document.images.photoslider.src=photos[which];
 }

 function forward(){
     which = (which + 1) % photos.length;               //  modulus keeps which within
     document.images.photoslider.src=photos[which];     // the bounds, while incrementing
 }
```

going backward, if which is 0 or less, jump to the last photo. Going forward, if which + 1 == photos.length, the modulus will zero it out, looping you back to the beginning.

Comment: this works great when moving from the  image4 back to the image1!
however for somereason when selecting back from image1 it skips image 4 and image3 appears

Comment: fixed. I left ` document.images.photoslider.src=photos[which];` inside the else.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function backward(){
    if (which>0){
     which=which-1;
    } else {
     which=photos.length-1;
    }
    document.images.photoslider.src=photos[which];
 }

 function forward(){
    if (which<photos.length-1){
     which=which+1;
    } else {
     which=0;
    }
   document.images.photoslider.src=photos[which];
 }
```

tada!

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<p> click on the button to change the image</p>

     <input type="button" value="&lt;&lt;Back" onClick="backward()"> 

     <img src = "youtube.png" value = "PREVIOUS" id = "prev">


     <input type="button" value="Next&gt;&gt;" onClick="forward()">





<script>

var photos = new Array()
 var i=0
 photos[0]='youtube.png';    //enter the path of the image here
 photos[1]='facebook.png';
 photos[2]='twitter.png';
 photos[3]='sirius_logo_sm.gif';


function backward(){
    if (i>0){
     i=i-1;
    } else {
     i=photos.length-1;
    }
    document.getElementById("prev").src=photos[i];
 }

 function forward()
 {
    if (i<photos.length-1){
     i=i+1;
    } else {
     i=0;
    }
 document.getElementById("prev").src=photos[i]; }


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please take the time to explain why your answer is correct instead of a code dump.

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".